# Map a string to an array index consistently (hash function)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Given any string "blah", or "whee", I want to consistently return return a value from the array:

```
myfunc("blah")  -> 1
myfunc("whee")  -> 2
myfunc("three") -> 3
myfunc("blah")  -> 1
```

Any suggestions?  I'm using ruby, but any pseudocode will do.  The string will actually be URLs, so I don't know the possibilities ahead of time.

There will be a limited number, but probably close to 50,000, so it'd be better to avoid storing each one.

I'd like a roughly random distribution, but if it's skewed, or one element is very rare, that is fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Question is not clear. 1, 2, 3, 1 is not consistent. You mentioned "blah" and "whee", but how are they different from other strings?

Comment: sounds like you want a hash with h[url] = h.size

Comment: added example solution that could be expanded on

Comment: Should probably edit the question instead of adding an answer.  So you have an array of N elements, and want to consistently map a given string to the same element, but other than repeatability it's not important which index it gets mapped to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in the right direction, I think.

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5]

"whee".split('').collect {|c| c.ord}.inject{|sum, x| sum + x} % my_array.size
```

Using this, you would always map a string to an index in the array.

Also, instead of 1,2,3,4... you could make the same association using any unique random numbers in the array, since the mod operand returns an index, not a value.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to return an item from an array for any string, you don't care what item, but you want it to be the same every time.

If that is so, you can use the [`hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-hash) method:

```
def myfunc(obj)
  a = [1,2,3,4,5]
  a[obj.hash % a.size]
end
myfunc("blah")  -> 5
myfunc("whee")  -> 4
myfunc("three") -> 2
myfunc("blah")  -> 5
```

Comment: +1 What the OP wants is a hashing operation. This is the only correct answer IMHO.

Comment: Chances of different strings returning the same number are big. Also, this would yield to different numbers in different Ruby sessions.

Comment: There's a "hash" method, nice!  This would be perfect except as steenslag says, it's not consistent across ruby sessions.  So I'm running with Tiago's answer for now, thank you though, very informative!